# Drawing map in R without boundaries

Tags: r, dictionary

I'm plotting the map of Europe using

```
  library(rworldmap)
  newmap <- getMap(resolution = "high")
  plot(newmap, xlim = c(-10, 30), ylim = c(25, 65), asp = 1)
```

Is it possible not to plot the boundaries between countries but just the boundaries between the sea and the land ?

I can achieve this with

```
map('world', xlim = c(-10, 30), ylim = c(25, 65), asp = 1, interior=FALSE)
```

But I don't like the resolution much.

Comment: What about `library(mapdata) ; data(worldHiresMapEnv) ; map('worldHires', xlim = c(-10, 30), ylim = c(25, 65), asp = 1, interior=FALSE)` ?

Comment: This works but the resolution is not as good as `rworldmap`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get really fine resolution *and* just land borders from Natural Earth (you can also get lower resolution ones). The price you pay is time to process/plot (R is not speedy with complex/polygons).

The following:

- grabs & imports the best res Natural Earth land borders
- clips it to the bounding box you specified
- simplifies the borders (this is where you get to tweak for resolution/time tradeoff)
- clips the simplified borders
- plots a 2x2 comparison grid

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)

URL <- "http://naciscdn.org/naturalearth/10m/physical/ne_10m_land.zip"
fil <- basename(URL)
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)

shp <- grep("shp$", unzip(fil), value=TRUE)

world <- readOGR(shp, ogrListLayers(shp)[1], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
world_clip <- gIntersection(as(extent(-10, 30, 25, 65), "SpatialPolygons"),
                            world, byid=TRUE)

# tweak 0.05 up/down as needed
world_simpl <- gSimplify(world, 0.05)
world_simpl_clip <- gIntersection(as(extent(-10, 30, 25, 65), "SpatialPolygons"),
                            world_simpl, byid=TRUE)

par(mfrow=c(2,2), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(world, xlim = c(-10, 30), ylim = c(25, 65), asp = 1)
plot(world_clip, asp = 1)
plot(world_simpl, xlim = c(-10, 30), ylim = c(25, 65), asp = 1)
plot(world_simpl_clip, asp = 1)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Even thinner lines aren't going to remove the (IMO) ugly coastlines at smaller display/print sizes, but you can tweak the simplification component to achieve your own personal aesthetic & time balance.